# Using ksort to sort by year and month with php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This is my php function which returns an array of year, month and associative values

```
function byCalendarMonth($tmpArray) {
    $output = [];
    foreach ($tmpArray as $value) {
        $year = date('Y', strtotime($value['date']));
        $month = date('M', strtotime($value['date']));

        if (empty($output[$year][$month]))
            $output[$year][$month] = ['Indoor' => 0, 'Gym class' => 0];
        // Check for incident intensity
        $output[$year][$month][$value['category']] += $value['score'];
    }

    ksort($output);
    ksort($output[$year][$month]);
    return $output;
}
```

and the output looks like

```
Array
(
    [2016] => Array
        (
            [Dec] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 39
                    [Gym class] => 34
                )

            [Nov] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 56
                    [Gym class] => 41
                )

            [Oct] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 82
                    [Gym class] => 66
                )

            [Sep] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 97
                    [Gym class] => 89
                )

            [Aug] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 74
                    [Gym class] => 78
                )

            [Jul] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 0
                    [Gym class] => 3
                )

            [Jun] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 74
                    [Gym class] => 98
                )

            [May] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 102
                    [Gym class] => 58
                )

            [Apr] => Array
                (
                    [Gym class] => 49
                    [Indoor] => 106
                )

        )

    [2017] => Array
        (

            [Mar] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 67
                    [Gym class] => 53
                )

            [Feb] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 81
                    [Gym class] => 47
                )

            [Jan] => Array
                (
                    [Indoor] => 84
                    [Gym class] => 49
                )

        )

)
```

But I just need the months to ASC like jan, feb, mar etc??

Comment: your key is wrong it should be Gym_class or Gym-class or Gym @alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few solutions.

First. If you know exactly range of years, you can generate empty array with years and months. In this, you will never miss any month. Something like that...

```
$years = [];
for ($year = 2015; $year <= 2017; $year++ ) {
  $years[$year] = ['Jan' => [], 'Feb' => [], ...];
}
```

Second. You can replace ksort($output[$year][$month]) to

```
$listOfOrderedMonth = ['Jan', 'Feb', ...];


$result = [];
foreach ($output as $year => $months) {
    foreach ($listOfOrderedMonth as $orderedMonth) {
        $result[$year][$orderedMonth] = $months[$orderedMonth];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second solution did the trick and is one I can understand

Comment: Oh one followup question how would i skip the beginning and end months if they are out of the date range?? (FYI: I am plotting a Google Chart) –

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
ksort($output[$year][$month]);
```

with

```
$month_names = ['Jan','Feb'...];
foreach($output as $year) {
   uksort($year, 
          function($a, $b) use($month_names) {
             return array_search($a, $month_names, true) - array_search($b, $month_names, true);
          }); 
}
```

[uksort function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)

[array_search function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Oh one followup question how would i skip the beginning and end months if they are out of the date range?? (FYI: I am plotting a Google Chart) –

Comment: don't put in array while creating it by usual check